# How to get next element and update in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have following codes :

```
<td>
<input type="button" name="btndelete" value="Delete" onclick="Delete(this)" />
<input type="hidden" name="hiddentxt" value="1" />
</td>
```

And I want to update hidden field value when I click btndelete button.
I want to update value only with pure javascript and also cannot give id for hidden field.

I have tried as follow :

```
function Delete(e){
    // I have other logic scripts.

    e.nextSibling.innerHTML = "updated value";
    }
}
```

But cannot update. Kindly help with this.

Comment: use `e.nextSibling.value = "updated value";`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Delete(e){
    // I have other logic scripts.

    e.nextSibling.value = "updated value";
    }
}
```

You need to update the value for an input DOM node